# jQuery Ajax passing value on select (onchange) in php variable on same page without form posting

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How to retrieve:

```html
<div id="test">
  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['sweets']))
    {
      ob_clean();
      echo $_POST['sweets'];
      exit;
    }
  ?>
</div>

<form id="a" action="" method="post">
  <select name="sweets" onchange="change()" id="select1">
    <option >Chocolate</option>
    <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
    <option >Taffy</option>
    <option >Caramel</option>
    <option >Fudge</option>
    <option >Cookie</option>
  </select>
</form>

   <!-- Script -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function change() {
    var sweets = $("#select1").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: { sweets: sweets },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#test").html(data);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

passing value to php string:

```
$string = $_POST['sweets'];
<!-- I'm looking for this: -->
```

I hope this is possible. I've looked around stackoverflow and google for an answer but could not find one for my purpose.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php and how they serialize data from the form. In your case, the trigger will be your dropdown change instead of form.submit, but it doesn't change much. to the rest of the logic.

Answer (score 0):

For a same page ajax / PHP script, you may put the PHP at the top of the script and end it with `exit` (whole script enclosed within a `if condition statement` when there is data submitted by `POST`)

To make it more meaningful, you can consider returning something related to what you have submitted by POST (which is the type of sweet food), as an example let's show its general definition. We may use switch which is a commonly used statement/construct for this purpose (in particular to answer your question on `<!-- I'm looking for this: -->`):

```
switch ($string) {
    case "Chocolate":
        echo "Chocolate is made from cocoa beans, the dried and fermented seeds of the cacao tree";
        break;
    case "Candy":
        echo "Candy is a sweet food made from sugar or chocolate, or a piece of this";
        break;        
    case "Taffy":
        echo "Taffy is a type of candy invented in the United States, made by stretching and/or pulling a sticky mass of a soft candy base";
        break;
    case "Caramel":
        echo "Caramel is made of sugar or syrup heated until it turns brown, used as a flavouring or colouring for food or drink";
        break;
    case "Fudge":
        echo "Fudge is a dense, rich confection typically made with sugar, milk or cream, butter and chocolate or other flavorings";
        break;
    case "Cookie":
        echo "A cookie (American English) or biscuit (British English) is a baked snack or dessert that is typically small, flat, and sweet";
        break;
}     
  ?>
```

So the following is an example code:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['sweets'])) {
//      ob_clean();

$string = $_POST['sweets'];

switch ($string) {
    case "Chocolate":
        echo "Chocolate is made from cocoa beans, the dried and fermented seeds of the cacao tree";
        break;
    case "Candy":
        echo "Candy is a sweet food made from sugar or chocolate, or a piece of this";
        break;        
    case "Taffy":
        echo "Taffy is a type of candy invented in the United States, made by stretching and/or pulling a sticky mass of a soft candy base";
        break;
    case "Caramel":
        echo "Caramel is made of sugar or syrup heated until it turns brown, used as a flavouring or colouring for food or drink";
        break;
    case "Fudge":
        echo "Fudge is a dense, rich confection typically made with sugar, milk or cream, butter and chocolate or other flavorings";
        break;
    case "Cookie":
        echo "A cookie (American English) or biscuit (British English) is a baked snack or dessert that is typically small, flat, and sweet";
        break;

  }
      exit;
} 
?>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <select name="sweets" onchange="change()" id="select1">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option >Chocolate</option>
    <option >Candy</option>
    <option >Taffy</option>
    <option >Caramel</option>
    <option >Fudge</option>
    <option >Cookie</option>
  </select>
<br><br>
<div id="test"></div>

<script>
  function change() {
    var sweets = $("#select1").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: { sweets: sweets },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#test").html(data);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

See [Demo](https://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/SOanswer23mar2024.php)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but you misunderstood me.

I don't need <div id="test"></div>
 
I'm looking for this:
<?php
$string = $_POST['sweets'];
?>

<h1><?= $string ?></h1>

I will use the result further down the page.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of `$("#test").html(data);` in your ajax return ??

Comment: In this case, I'm using ready-made code that I can probably use in my page with a few edits.

Comment: Returning something (data) on success is actually one of the core functions/purposes of ajax, and we normally need to have some "container" in order to display the data that is returned, that's why your original code has `$("#test").html(data);` and `<div id="test"></div>`. It is nothing to do with "I'm using ready-made code".

Comment: Maybe I'm not asking the question correctly.

I want to get value=" " from <select> <option> in php variable in same page without
<form>
--
</form>
posting.